# Passing item value in PLSQL dynamic content in ORACLE APEX for where clause using button?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-5

I want to pass items in PLSQL dynamic content region to be used for where clause. Is this not possible or I just did it wrong?

I tried to set variable with item value and add it to where clause but it seems not working.

I also tried to print the item value to check if it is passing through plsql dynamic content but its not.

THIS IS MY SAMPLE CODE:

```
declare
 v_year number := :P1_year;
 cursor c_tasks is 
   select task_name, assigned_to
     from eba_ut_chart_tasks
    where year >= :P1_year;
 
begin
  sys.htp.p('<table>');
  sys.htp.p('<tr>');
  for a in c_tasks loop
    sys.htp.p('<td>' || a.task_name || ' (' || a.assigned_to || ')</td>' );
   end loop;
  sys.htp.p('</tr>');
  sys.htp.p('</table>');



  sys.htp.p(v_year);
end;
```

After pressing search Button to refresh the region, table still doesn`t filter.
I also tried putting the value in variable just to see if its passing through the PLSQL content but still not working.

Comment: Can't tell. You said that "you want" but it "didn't work". Could you share some code you used to do that? Or even create an example on apex.oracle.com, share login developer's credentials so that someone might have a look?

Comment: Please be more precise. Show us what you're trying to achieve with on the emp sample table. What you are describing is extremely vague

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: sorry. what i want to do is create a filter for PLSQL dynamic content report table that I created. when I include the items for where clause its not working. What I did is pass item to where clause. Is there any option to filter the table or I just did the wrong thing using the item for where clause?

Comment: Please provide the code sample.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample table contents:

```
SQL> select * from eba_ut_chart_tasks;

      YEAR TASK_N ASSIGN
---------- ------ ------
      2015 Task 1 Little
      2022 Task 2 Foot
      2032 Task 3 Scott

SQL>
```

In Apex, I created a region whose type is "Dynamic content". It contains a select list item for *years* and submits the page when a new value is chosen:

```
select distinct year d, year r from eba_ut_chart_tasks order by year;
```

As Apex requires, its (region's) source is a **function** (body that returns a CLOB) so - let it return *something* (`NULL` will do). Also, `<tr>` tags should be include into the loop, otherwise you'll get everything in only one row.

```
declare
  cursor c_tasks is 
    select task_name, assigned_to
      from eba_ut_chart_tasks
      where year >= :P1_YEAR;
 begin
  sys.htp.p('<table>');
  for a in c_tasks loop
    sys.htp.p('<tr><td>' || a.task_name || ' (' || a.assigned_to || ')</td></tr>' );
  end loop;
  sys.htp.p('</table>');

  return null;
end;
```

When executed:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I just use this as a sample. 
My problem is about where clause. I think your sample is from latest apex. My apex version is 5.1 and from region i just selected PLSQL DYNAMIC CONTENT and what i have here is just PLSQL without something to return. Theres no such thing like item/s to submit on my version unlike in latest apex. I already populated a table design i just did this sample to know if my syntax is correct in sending items to PLSQL DYNAMIC CONTENT.

Comment: To me, yes - code you posted should return *something* and display the result, regardless of Apex version. If you didn't get it, then P1_YEAR item isn't in session state so query doesn't "see" it and returns *nothing*. The simplest option to do that (put item's value into session state) is to **submit** the page. Did you do that? If not, try to do it. Either by setting select item's property, or create a **button** which submits the page after you select P1_YEAR's value. BTW, perhaps it is time to **upgrade**. Apex 5.1 seems to be rather old.

Comment: Your right its not in session state. thank you.